# How to properly map hierarchical JPA entities to a dto model (to save and update via rest)

Tags: json, jpa

I have an 2 level entity hierarchy (Post and PostComments; one OneToMany relation) and implemented it [this suggested way](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/) (in short: owner is the many side, and there are dedicate methods on one-side to add and remove sub entities).

While this is working fine i am struggling at map this in a proper DTO (to be json-ed). I don't want to expose the entities directly.
 Proper means especially that i can do 
json->mapToEntity->repository.save(entity)

This should then update all Post fields but also all PostComment fields (add remove as needed).

The only way i see at the moment is to completely reconstruct the entity on update: Retrieve the entity to be updated and set all fields as given by json, then save.

Is there a better way to update such an entity structure via json model (rest api)

Comment: Do you mean JSON string?

Answer (score 0):

I would write mapping methods by own, like you have it already. In this way you can fully control what is happening. E.g. when mapping back Entity to JSON you may not need map all lazy collections, based on use case. Using mapping frameworks this would be a struggle.

Comment: in my case the i need always eager fetch - the list of children is short and there is no use case of parent element without the children (Post and Comments were only used for explaination)